# Element Values on Weapons

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

Most of the time I just used the weapon with the highest element value of what I needed, but now I thought about it and dont really have an idea what the value really means.

For example the Kut-Ku Pair:
it does 154 raw damage and 190 fire damage.

does this mean I do on each hit 154+190 (effected by the resistence of the monster i assume) damage?

Comment: what weapon(type) are you using?

Comment: Mostly glaives and Dual Blades

Comment: The short and long of it is that each move for a given weapon has a coefficient. This coefficient will modify how much raw damage goes in, and is modified by a monster's hitbox and weapon sharpness. Elemental works similarly, but is also subject to resistances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gaijin Hunter wrote a really in depth guide on how damage is calculated](http://gaijinhunter.tumblr.com/post/73946102476/mh4-how-damage-calculation-works-simplified).

The oversimplified result of damage is just: **Damage = [Physical damage] + [Elemental Damage] * Overall Defense.**

There is also things to take note of when attacking. Weapon power, motion value, and sharpness all play a part in the "Physical" calculations.

"Elemental" calculation is determined by "shown amount" / 10 x resistance.

Overall Defense is everything from the Monster's resistances, The type of quest (caravan, gathering hall, low rank, high rank, G) food bonus, etc.

The numbers you see on the weapons are very much "increased" than what you will actually do. In the example used on the guide (Shagara Charge Blade) has 648 damage and 230 dragon element, but attacking the Shagara's head deals a total of **28** damage once all calculations are done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this leads me to two other questions
1. what is "motion value"
2. would it than be better to just stick to raw damage than to use elemental weapons?

Comment: Motion value is basically how "strong" an attack is. Giajin Hunter explains it on the guide I posted as "This is the value each attack has. Hunters go through a lot of trouble to figure out these numbers, typically by kicking small monsters to death than using one of a move then seeing how many kicks on top of that is required to kill it. The slower the animation = the higher the number = the more damage it does."

Comment: as for using raw or element, generally fast attacking weapons (like dual swords) benefit greatly from the boosted damage of element, whereas slow weapons like greatsword it really doesn't help much. I didn't want to just copy paste the whole guide... but if you just read that it explains everything... *everything*.

Comment: sharpness level also affects elemental damage as well

Comment: It's worth noting that Overall Defence is a percentage value.